# FFmpeg color correction algorithm

Tags: ffmpeg, colors, algorithm

I'm trying to sync CSS and FFmpeg color correction. The goal is to create tool that converts CSS bri-sat-con-gam filter values to corresponding ffmpeg vals and vice versa.

e.g.

> ```
> -vf "eq=brightness=0.3:saturation=1.3:contrast=1.1"
> ```

→

> ```
> filter="brightness(30%) saturate(130%) contrast(110%)"
> ```

While algorithms for CSS properties are available at W3C, I have failed to find ones for FFmpeg. I've tried to dig GitHub. Starting from [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/be37a669714094b9321f9f6f2947a296fe020483/libavfilter/vf_eq.c#L107-L155) I've unfolded function calls, but it looks "a bit" too hard to navigate in 20 years and 104k commits old project. :)

I'll be very grateful if anyone can help me to figure out precise formulas for brightness, saturation, contrast, and gamma. Any hints. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the core function:

```
static void create_lut(EQParameters *param)
{
    int i;
    double   g  = 1.0 / param->gamma;
    double   lw = 1.0 - param->gamma_weight;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        double v = i / 255.0;
        v = param->contrast * (v - 0.5) + 0.5 + param->brightness;

        if (v <= 0.0) {
            param->lut[i] = 0;
        } else {
            v = v * lw + pow(v, g) * param->gamma_weight;

            if (v >= 1.0)
                param->lut[i] = 255;
            else
                param->lut[i] = 256.0 * v;
        }
    }

    param->lut_clean = 1;
}
```

The filter operates only on 8-bit YUV inputs. This function creates a Look Up Table mapping all 8-bit input values 0-255 to output values. Then this table is applied to the input pixels.

The functions with names of the form *set_parameter* like `set_gamma` convert the user supplied argument to the final value used in the above function. `contrast` is applied only to the luma plane; saturation to the chroma planes.

Comment: @CorvusCorax – [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)